StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent
I've this situation:
server side:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Action(byte[] value)
    {
        var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);
        var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SampleObject>(jsonString);

        return Ok(myObject);
    }
}

Client:
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await SendObjectAsync();
    }
    
    private static  async Task SendObjectAsync()
    {
        var myObject = new SampleObject();

        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

        using var client = new HttpClient();
    
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
    
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5287/Main", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var returnedObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SampleObject>(responseData);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {returnedObject!.Text},{returnedObject.Number}");
        }
    }
}

In the response i get always this error:
StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2024 21:48:40 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}

I also tried to add the FromBody attribute in the Action params, but without success.
Can someone please explain? I want to send binary raw data.
Thanks.

I wonder why your client code is trying to do a POST to the endpoint address http://localhost:5287/Main. If I'm not mistaken it should be doing a POST to http://localhost:5287/Test/Action instead.

I had the same question. Also I dont really understand why you try to add a streaming request header in your client, while you're trying to submit a json.
You should set your content-type to: "application/json";

If it is possible to directly send the serialized object in byte[] without passing from json it is fine anyway

The issue you are facing stems from the fact that the ApiController convention assumes JSON by default when deserializing request bodies. Since you’re sending binary data with the application/octet-stream content type, the model binding isn't expecting that type of content and returns an error.
You can fix by changing de content to json or by creating a custom model binding:
public class ByteArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SampleObject>(jsonString);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class ByteArrayModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelType == typeof(SampleObject))
        {
            return new ByteArrayModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ByteArrayModelBinderProvider());
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Action([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ByteArrayModelBinder))] SampleObject myObject)
{
    return Ok(myObject);
}

